# Login failed after cloning live wordpress site to local wampserver

Tags: login, wp-config

This is what I did:

1. Copy all files in public_html to C:\wamp\www\mylocalsite.com
2. Export my database and rename all http://mylivesite.com to http://localhost/mylocalsite.com of exported .sql file using notepad++
3. Change database name, database username and database password in wp-config.php to my new database name, username and password that I created in my local phpmyadmin

All done with no error. When I try to login using mylivesite.com login data, but it failed with no error notification.

My question is there any easy solution for me so then I can login to my localsite admin dashboard successfully?

Comment: I did try: reset password in database with MD5 dropdown option, but login still failed

Comment: Assuming you see the login page? (`wp-login.php`)..is the (*local*) site visible, did you think about the path...it seems you moved from root to sub-folder.. you add(changed) that also in the db? Maybe you find [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) some help. Btw wamp means Microsoft OS... did you add the site also in the host file? (*windows/system32/drivers/etc/*) Or is that `localhost` part in the last given url a mistake?

Comment: Hello @Charles thanks for your fast reply, Yes I can see wp-login.php login page, but the (local) site is not visible. It said 'The requested URL not found..' maybe it is because of plugins. Actually this is the reason why I need to login to my local site admin dashboard in order to disable all plugin thx

Comment: A very quick response, which probably not solves login but ..anyway...rename the `plugins` folder and plugins are disabled. Should I make an answer with a 'dirty' workaround about copy to local and work without too many changes with MS/Wamp and your information?

Comment: Hello @Charles I did rename the plugins folder and yes it is not the one that make my login failed thx

Answer (score 1):

Here a - *quick and dirty way* - to get 'live to local' with wamp.

Assuming that you access your live site as in `http://yoursite.com`

Steps to take:

- Copy your live site as you did, public_html to www
- Edit `wp-config.php` and add folowing 2 lines code:

  ```
  define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://local.yoursite.com' );
  define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://local.yoursite.com' );
  ```

  IF these lines already exist change them by adding `local.` as shown (*with the dot*).
- Change in `wp-config.php` also the credentials for `DB_NAME`, `DB_USER` and `DB_PASSWORD`.
   (*don't forget the `$table_prefix` if you changed that also with your new credentials*).
- Edit your downloaded `*.sql` file and make the changes, meaning by
  that just add **local.**
   in front of the domain name (*every time you find that url*) and change also:
  `DB_NAME`, `DB_USER` and `DB_PASSWORD`. 
  (*don't forget the `$table_prefix` if you changed that also!*) with your new credentials.
  (*Do a search for http://yourdomain.com in that `*.sql`file*)
- Edit windows `hosts` file *(C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc)*, add a new line with
   `127.0.0.1   local.yoursite.com`
- Import now the changed `*.sql` file into phpMyAdmin
- Pray and open browser, type `local.yoursite.com` if all went okay it should work flawless.

When all went okay you can now add/edit local and still access live without any hasle.